# Increase MongoDB maximum number of connections

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongoid

I am getting some errors on MongoDB side, the error is complaining that it reached the max allowed connections.

Wondering if there is anyway to increase the max number of allowed connections.

Comment: Related info here - http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/59b0648351202d8b?pli=1

Comment: How many connections do you usually have open at once? How many do you want to have?

Comment: I am writing a  mutlithreading app using mongoid, # max conn should around ~20-30.... or i shouldn't use multithreading with mongoid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the MongoDB documentation:

http://www.mongodb.org/

use this command line argument:

```
--maxConns arg       max number of simultaneous connections
```

You might want to check this:  http://blog.boxedice.com/2011/06/08/mongodb-connection-overhead/