# MongoDB replica set. Insert fine. Cannot remove

Tags: php, mongodb, replicaset

Strangely, insert operation works fine, but not remove.
I am using MongoDB 3.0.1 replica set, PHP Driver > 1.5.4 and Apache server

Already looked through the discussion [MongoConnectionException - No candidate servers found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595172/mongoconnectionexception-no-candidate-servers-found).

My code works like:

```
\MongoLog::setModule( \MongoLog::ALL );
\MongoLog::setLevel( \MongoLog::ALL );
$m = new \MongoClient($this->dbConnectionstring, $this->dbOptions); 
$db = $m->$dbName;                         
$c = $db->$collectionName;
try{
$affected = $c->remove($criteria);
} catch (\MongoException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

However, it shows only a single line:

```
CON     INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a REPLSET connection (write)
```

I've tried a shorter `is_master_interval`, `ping_interval` and restarted Apache.

It doesn't work.

The connection to my remote replica set is fine, because Mongo Management Studio is working fine.

It can show `rs.status()` just like:

```
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-14T12:15:30.291Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "HIDDEN:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 528078,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1436862181, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T08:23:01Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-14T12:15:29.982Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-14T12:15:29.982Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "HIDDEN:27017",
            "configVersion" : 633800
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "HIDDEN:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 528078,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1436862181, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T08:23:01Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-14T12:15:29.989Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-14T12:15:29.985Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "HIDDEN:27017",
            "configVersion" : 633800
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "HIDDEN:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 528220,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1436862181, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T08:23:01Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1436844293, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T03:24:53Z"),
            "configVersion" : 633800,
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Is your connection using an authenticated user? If so are you aware that the `.remove()` action may not be a part of the allowed [privelleges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#security-user-actions) on that account? I would hope that such an error would be more specific. But if you can "read" and if you can "insert" then it seems logcial that the account may not have the privellage to "remove".

Comment: I'm not using any authentication. After PHP driver 1.4 there is a built-in blacklist, i wonder if my PHP driver is blocking itself. Restarting Apache should reset the blacklist but still not working.