# mongodb connection timeout issues with only 3 users

Tags: mongodb, scaling

I'm writing an new version of a website using fuel PHP 1.5 and mongodb 2.4.3.  Right now we're  just getting the initial batch of pages set up to verify that the technology works.  The issue that I'm running into, and this is more so an issue for my coworkers then myself, is that periodically it just won't connect to the server.  It returns a generic -

"Fuel\Core\Mongo_DbException [ Error ]: Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: 166.78.248.139:27017: Timed out after 0 ms"

but... if you refresh the page this often goes away.  I should mention that the overall DB size right now is tiny, (we're using 'newsite'): [
  otherhook      0.203125GB
  local          0.078125GB
  newsite        0.203125GB
  test           0.203125GB
]
and the server has 2GB of RAM.  There are a grand total of 3 of us trying to connect to and use the box.  I might also add that I've only seen this error once the 3rd person started working on it, but not before.  ...alright that's as much information as I've got.

Anyone have any ideas as to what's really causing this?  Any idea on how to fix it so that we don't have these intermittent connection errors?

Comment: What is the actual connection string you are using? The error message seems to indicate that you are setting one of the timeout options.. Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: The string that fuel PHP uses?  
<?php
/**
 * The Development database settings.
 */

return array(
 'active' => 'default',
 'mongo' => array(
        // This group is used when no instance name has been provided.
        'default' => array(
            'hostname' => '<actual ip address here>',
            'database' => 'rift',
        )
 )
);

Not sure how to check what version of the mongodb driver I'm using.  Should be the latest one. (Did the whole setup like 3 weeks ago).  PHP is at version 5.3.10 on the remote server and 5.3.15 locally.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fuel, can you find out what exactly is sent to the Mongo (or MongoClient) class? - And which version of the MongoDB extension are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the MongoDB logs, and in particular look for issues with it running out of resources when trying to open connections (there will usually be a warning printed at start up too relating to ulimits being too low or similar).  You haven't mentioned what OS you are running on, but if it Linux, then the settings you are looking for are documented here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

For OS X, take a look here:

https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll dive into that a bit later (I think I may have figured it out).  Presently myself and the 2 dev's are using Mac OS X to do local dev against the mongoDB, and our (not yet live) webserver is using linux to hit the same resource.  What's common about all of them is the use of apache... which according to this thread- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249768/php-mongo-error-reading-from-socket

may have been the issue.  I'm going to mess with it some more and see if that was it.  Update to come.

Comment: No complaints about used up system resources.