# 'No candidate servers found' mongo error

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I think I've found a reoccurance of a bug, but I'm not able to fully confirm if it is.  We're currently using version 1.5.5 of the Mongo php driver.  The steps I use to recreate this is as follows:

1. Start up two mongo servers and put them in a replica set
2. Load up php connecting to mongo and the replica set
3. Take down the secondary mongo server and start it back up
4. Load up the php connecting to mongo.

I get a 'No candidate servers found' but about one in every 10 attempts of loading up the php page.  Restarting Apache fixes this problem.  So to me it feels very simialr to this:

[PHP Mongo Error reading from socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249768/php-mongo-error-reading-from-socket)

But it does say this is fixed.  I've captured this error with logging on:

```
Notice: PARSE INFO: Parsing mongodb://ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017,ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Found node: ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Found node: ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Connection type: MULTIPLE in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Found option 'replicaSet': 'ghood' in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Switching connection type: REPLSET in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE INFO: - Found option 'connectTimeoutMS': 120000 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: PARSE WARN: - Replacing previously set value for 'connectTimeoutMS' (60000) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: found connection ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 (looking for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: found connection ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 (looking for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a REPLSET connection (read) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: found connection ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 (looking for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON INFO: is_ping: pinging ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: No timeout changes for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Destroying connection object for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Closing socket for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523. in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON WARN: Couldn't connect to 'ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017': Remote server has closed the connection in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: found connection ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 (looking for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523) in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON INFO: is_ping: pinging ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: No timeout changes for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Destroying connection object for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Closing socket for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523. in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON WARN: Couldn't connect to 'ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017': Remote server has closed the connection in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: discover_topology: checking ismaster for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON WARN: discover_topology: couldn't create a connection for ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON FINE: discover_topology: checking ismaster for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: CON WARN: discover_topology: couldn't create a connection for ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017;ghood;.;4523 in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: finding candidate servers in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: - all servers in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: - collect any in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: adding connections: in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: done in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: limiting to servers with same replicaset name in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: limiting to servers with same replicaset name: done in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: limiting by credentials in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Notice: REPLSET FINE: limiting by credentials: done in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'No candidate servers found' in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php(8): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://ny1-u...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /ext1/FIDMGR/sdtk/htdocs/rick.php on line 8
```

The code I use to debug is very simple:

```
<?

MongoLog::setModule( MongoLog::ALL );
MongoLog::setLevel( MongoLog::ALL );

error_reporting( E_ALL );

$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017,ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017',Array('replicaSet' => 'ghood', "connectTimeoutMS" => 120000));
$mongo->setReadPreference(MongoClient::RP_NEAREST);

$userColl = $mongo->user->users;

var_dump($mongo->getConnections);
var_dump($mongo->getReadPreference());
```

Is there anything else I can look into to see why this is happening?

Could it be a set up issue I'm hitting here?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem since upgrading the servers to 2.6.x and driver 1.5.5. Except my servers are running fine. It can happen without taking down any of the servers and the primary in the replica set has not changed. It usually happens on background scripts that run regularly, so there's not even a web server involved. It has happened a couple times on my web server, but I use nginx and php-fpm. I haven't had to restart. I'm running on AWS so I wonder if there is an occasional network issue. I just noticed my connectTimeoutMS is 100. I'm going to try raising that value.

Answer (score 1):

I notice your log says `Couldn't connect to 'ny1-uutp-fdsa-31:27017': Remote server has closed the connection` and then it finds `ny1-uutp-fdsa-32:27017`. But then the connection to that server is also closed. It then tries to find a new master and can't connect to either. So maybe you are hitting the correct error message. Are you shutting both servers down by accident when you think you are only shutting down one?

Try lowering the `mongo.is_master_interval` down to 1 or 2 seconds in your php.ini. That should help php look for a new master server sooner. The default is 15 seconds.

Also, when the php driver is unable to connect to a server, it puts it on a blacklist and will not attempt to connect again until the `mongo.ping_interval` has expired. So if you take a server down and then bring it back up, it will take that long until php attempts to connect to it again. The default value for that is 5 seconds.

I see your connection timeout is 120000 which is two minutes. That also seems way too long. As I noted in the comments to your question, I'm having a similar problem, but my connection timeout is only 100 milliseconds which may be too short. Maybe try 5000.

So adjust your ping_interval and is_master_interval to be a few seconds and restart apache. Also change your code to have a shorter connect timeout. Make sure you are only taking down and bringing back one of your servers. Then wait until the sum of your intervals and timeouts have passed and see if the problem persists. If so, I think this could warrant opening a ticket with MongoDB. I'll let you know if the problems I have seen still occur after raising my connection timeout.

I similarly have read the [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-158) you linked to. I found these PHP MongoDB driver tips and tricks posted by MongoLab to be helpful: http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/05/mongodb-driver-tips-tricks-php/

Comment: Thanks for this.  We're trying these tips now and I'll let you know what we find.

Comment: So just to clarify the first bit, no we are only taking down one server.  I've even had the mongo interface open on the primary to make sure it's open and I can see the status of the master and the down standby.

Comment: Good luck. I raised my connect timeout to 2 seconds and have not experienced this error yet for my scenario.