# mongodb : help needed to know for connection information

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb as the Database for our WebApplication

Currently we are facing a issue in mongoDb which is "max connections 8000 exceeded"

To solve this problem we have decided to increase the connections to 20000

But not sure how to increase the connections in MongoDB .

Currently we have only  this property  called maxConnections whose vaue is 800 in our code

This is the stats collected from  mongodb server

```
db.serverStatus().connections

{ "current" : 7000, "available" : 1000 }
```

We start the mongodb this way

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

and inside the mongodb.conf we have

```
replSet = test
fork    = true
port    = 27017
```

**I am not sure why the max conection is showing 8000** ?? where it is hardcoded ??

Could any body please tell me how to find why the connection size is 8000 in my case ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase MongoDB maximum number of connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693989/increase-mongodb-maximum-number-of-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually have over 8000 threads access this database concurrently? Perhaps you are instead just spinning up a ton of connections you don't actually need?

That said, the 8000 limit is probably coming from your system limits. `ulimit` will restrict the number of usable sockets, which will restrict the number of connections. See [the mongod documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#maxConns) for a complete explanation.

Your approach here, though, should probably be to make sure you're reusing connections rather than just creating tons of them, since it's extremely doubtful that you are actually running 8000 concurrent clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris , we have 600 concurrent users

Comment: Yeah, you're creating and discarding way too many connections then. Make sure you're reusing them where possible. As a bonus, this'll increase the performance of your app. :)

Comment: thaks , but i didn't understand this  statement "8000 limit is probably coming from your system limits". Could you please tell me what do you mean by this ?? thanks in advance

Comment: This will be system dependent, but for example, in Linux, there are limits placed on how many resources a given process or user can use. Try `man ulimit` for more information - if the system won't let Mongo use more than 8k sockets, then Mongo can't maintain more than 8k connectuions, no matter how it's configured.

Comment: so if a system allows more connections (for example if the man ulimit value  is 20000) , i can increase the mongodb connections know  ??

Comment: Correct. The limiting factor here isn't Mongo's limits, it's the system's imposed limits.

Comment: that was great answers i had  , is increasing ulimit to 20000 will have any impact on application performance ??